# Inductive proof on scala stream

Tags: algorithm, scala, stream, induction, proof-of-correctness

Can someone help me with how to reason inductively that this scala code

```
lazy val y : Stream[Int] = 1 #:: (y map (_ + 1))
```

produces a list of natural numbers from 1 onwards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value at position in `1 #:: whatever` is 1, so we know `y(0) = 1`.

At a greater position we have `y(n+1) = whatever(n)`. Here `whatever` is `y map (_+1)`, so `y(n+1) = (y map (_+1))(n)`.

We want to prove `forall n. y(n) = n + 1`.

We know this is true for `n = 0`, `y(0) = 1`

`(y.map(_+1))(n)` is simply `y(n) + 1`. This is what map does. So our formula above becomes `y(n+1) = y(n) + 1`.

Then trivially, if we know `y(n) = n+1`, then `y(n+1) = (n+1) + 1`. Result true at next rank. We get our proof by induction.

Comment: Thanks! :) That was simple haha.

Comment: It was indeed, not much use for the induction.